# Prepare statement for byte [] in java

Tags: java

I have one database table in which one column (declatationform) is of type "bytea"  i want to store images in this column so i have return one method which is

```
public void uploadRentProofDeclaration(final MultipartFile declarationForm,
        final int rentProofInfoId, int year) {

    String updateSql = "update plit_landlordinfo" + year
            + " set filename=?,declarationform=? where cid=?";
    getJdbcTemplate().execute(updateSql, new PreparedStatementCallback() {
        public Object doInPreparedStatement(
                final PreparedStatement pSstatement) throws SQLException,
                DataAccessException {
            pSstatement.setString(1, declarationForm.getOriginalFilename());

            try {
                pSstatement.setBinaryStream(2, new ByteArrayInputStream(
                        declarationForm.getBytes()), declarationForm
                        .getBytes().length);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            pSstatement.setInt(3, rentProofInfoId);

            pSstatement.execute();
            return null;
        }
    });
}
```

Here what is happening is file name is getting save but byte [] is not save still that column is blank in my table and it is not giving any error can any one help me what is the problem

Answer (score 0):

Note sure how the `getBytes()` from `declarationForm` works (ie. method is called twice)? Try to store byte array from getBytes() method.

```
 byte []bytes=declarationForm.getBytes();
 pSstatement.setBinaryStream(2, new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes),bytes.length);
```

Or you may also use PreparedStatement.setBytes() method.

```
 byte []bytes=declarationForm.getBytes();
 pSstatement.setBytes(2,bytes);
```